# Reduce function in c

Tags: c

So I'm trying learn how to reduce my lines of code, and I came across one of my "larger" functions I wanted to look at.

```c
int DTWDistance(int* x, int xsize, int* y, int ysize){
    const double LARGE_VALUE = 1e30;
    const int min_window = abs(xsize - ysize);
    int i, j, minj, maxj, window;
    double dist, min;
    double **distances = malloc((xsize + 1) * sizeof(double *));
    for(i = 0; i < xsize + 1; ++i)
        distances[i] = malloc((ysize + 1) * sizeof(double));

    window = 1*ysize;
    if(xsize > ysize)
        window = 1*xsize;

    if(window < min_window)
        window = min_window;

    for(i = 0; i <= xsize; ++i)
        for(j = 0; j <= ysize; ++j)
            distances[i][j] = LARGE_VALUE;

    distances[0][0] = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < xsize; ++i)
    {
        minj = i - window;
        if(minj < 0)
            minj = 0;
        maxj = i + window;
        if(maxj > ysize)
            maxj = ysize;
        for(j = minj; j < maxj; ++j)
        {
            dist = abs(x[i] - y[j]);
            min = distances[i][j];
            if(min > distances[i][j+1])
                min = distances[i][j+1];
            if(min > distances[i+1][j])
                min = distances[i+1][j];
            distances[i+1][j+1] = dist + min;
        }
    }

    dist = distances[xsize][ysize];

    for(i = 0; i < xsize + 1; ++i)
        free(distances[i]);
    free(distances);

    return dist;  
}
```

To me it looks alright, but it might be because I've looked so many times at it now. So now I'm gonna ask a fresh pair of eye to look at this. Can you see an easier way of writing this or should I just go with this?

**Note: this is for me to learn how I can write my code in another, maybe smarter way?**

**EDIT reduced code**

```c
//DTW - Dynamic Time Warping - Compare two -usually temporal- sequences
int DTWDistance(int* x, int xsize, int* y, int ysize){
    const int LARGE_VALUE = INT_MAX;
    int i, j, minj, maxj, fr, myMin, dist;
    int **distances = malloc((xsize + 1) * sizeof(int *));

    for(i = 0; i < xsize + 1; ++i)
        distances[i] = malloc((ysize + 1) * sizeof(int));

    for(i = 0; i <= xsize; ++i)
        for(j = 0; j <= ysize; ++j)
            distances[i][j] = LARGE_VALUE;

    distances[0][0] = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < xsize; ++i)
    {        
        minj = max(i - ysize, 0);
        maxj = min(i + ysize, ysize);
        
        for(j = minj; j < maxj; ++j)
        {
            dist = abs(x[i] - y[j]);
            fr =  min(distances[i][j + 1], distances[i + 1][j]);
            myMin = min(distances[i][j], fr);
            distances[i+1][j+1] = dist + myMin;
        }
    }

    dist = distances[xsize][ysize];

    for(i = 0; i < xsize + 1; ++i)
        free(distances[i]);
    free(distances);

    return dist;  
}
```

Comment: `1*xsize` - this can be most definitely "reduced".

Comment: This is a good example of me, not being able to see the small things i can remove/change, because I've look too much at it.. Thanks haha

Comment: You actually just helped me remove 4 lines of code already... @EugeneSh.

Comment: I would advise you to post this on the [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com), because your program already works as expected.

Comment: @AndySukowski-Bang Okay, I'm new to stackoverflow so I thought this was the only place! Thanks, will do

Comment: @AndySukowski-Bang when suggesting users post on CR it would be great if there was also a suggestion like "_Please read the relevant help center pages like '[What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)' and  '[How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)_". In the current form the post above would likely be closed because it doesn't have much of a description about what the function actually achieves.

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ Okay I will make sure to do that in the future.

Comment: In many (most?) instances, Lines of Code is a poor measure.  Personally, I'd rather see you ADD the open and close braces around your `if` bodies and `for` bodies... and adding some comments.

Comment: "To me it looks alright, " --> `abs(xsize - ysize)` is subject to `int` overflow.  No allocation checks.  I see focus on reducing source code size, but not improving functionality nor code clarity - two things I see as more valuable to consider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another simplification is using Variable Length Array.
If `xsize * ysize` is reasonable (up to about 100k) then you can use VLA with automatic storage (usually allocated on stack).

You can replace:

```
    double **distances = malloc((xsize + 1) * sizeof(double *));
    for(i = 0; i < xsize + 1; ++i)
        distances[i] = malloc((ysize + 1) * sizeof(double));
```

with

```
double distances[xsize + 1][ysize + 1];
```

and remove all deallocation code:

```
for(i = 0; i < xsize + 1; ++i)
        free(distances[i]);
    free(distances);
```

If sizes are large then you can use VLA with dynamic storage:

```
double (*distances)[ysize + 1] = malloc((xsize + 1) * sizeof *distances);
```

and free it at the end with:

`free(distances)`

VLAs have other advantages over more popular "array of arrays".
Single large allocations is generally a lot faster than a bunch of smaller ones. Moreover, accessing a true 2D array usually more cache friendly and easier to be autovectorized by a compiler.

Comment: my dtw could'nt get under 1700 for some reason, so can't seem to make this solution work?

Comment: If you are able to do it, can you try to implement it in the reduced code?

Answer (score 1):

A lot of your code can be reduced if you make use of `min` and `max` macros:

```
#define min(a, b) ((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b);
#define max(a, b) ((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b);
```

This makes it possible to turn this into one single line:

```
// Old:
min = distances[i][j];
if(min > distances[i][j+1])
    min = distances[i][j+1];
if(min > distances[i+1][j])
    min = distances[i+1][j];

// New:
// note: renamed 'min' to avoid naming conflict with macro
myMin = min(distances[i][j], min(distances[i][j + 1], distances[i + 1][j]);
```

Likewise:

```
if(minj < 0)
    minj = 0;
```

Could be replaced with:

```
minj = max(i - window, 0);
```

And:

```
if(maxj > ysize)
   maxj = ysize;
```

Could be:

```
maxj = min(i + window, ysize);
```

Again:

```
if(window < min_window)
    window = min_window;
```

Can be:

```
window = min(window, min_window);
```

There, I just turned your 51 line function into a 40 line function.

Comment: Thanks! made it look better

Comment: Make it inlined functions, instead of macros.

Comment: @wildplasser, the problem with functions is that it's arguments and return value must be `int`. What is very limiting and dangerous if `min`/`max` would be used for other types like `double` or `unsigned`. It may result in bugs that are very difficult to find. Operator (`?:`) will automatically handle promotions.

Comment: The problem with macros is: side effects. For functions: just create a set of min/max functions for each data type.

Comment: @wildplasser, IMO, it's enough to call those macros `MIN` and `MAX` to make them look macro-like. In practice, it's enough to warn caller to be careful about side-effects.